# How can I reflect changes on an array to my rendered html in lit-element?

Tags: javascript, arrays, web-component, lit-element

I have a simple array of 1,2,3 that I loop to render paragraphs. The problem is that whenever I add something like 4 to the array it doesn't appear on screen but the log shows the number 4 was added successfuly. How can I do it? I'm using lit-element 2.0.0 (version is very important, this.requestUpdate() doesn't work here but does in 2.3.1) Here's the code:

```
class XApp extends LitElement {

  static get properties() {
    return {
      items:{
        type:Array,
      }
    }
  }

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.items = [1,2,3];
  }

  firstUpdated(changedProperties) {
    if (super.firstUpdated) {
      super.firstUpdated(changedProperties);
    }
    const list = document.querySelector(".list");

    list.addEventListener("click", e => {
        console.log(e.target);
        'Origin: ', event.composedPath()[0];
    })
  }

  render() {
    return html`

      <ul class="list" @click="${(e) => console.log(e.currentTarget)}">
        <li class="item">Wash dishes</li>
        <li class="item">Walk your dog</li>
      </ul>

      <div
        <slot></slot>
        ${this.items.map(item => html`<p>${item}</p>`)}
      </div>

      <button @click="${this.change}">Change</button>

    `;
  }

  change(e){
    console.log("Try Change");
    this.items.unshift(4);
    console.log(this.items);
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need [this.requestUpdate](https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/guide/lifecycle#requestupdate) to update state in your function

```
change(e){
    console.log("Try Change");
    this.items.unshift(4);
    console.log(this.items);
    this.requestUpdate();
}
```

You can check here [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/puuhca?file=my-element.js), hope it helps

Comment: Hello! Thank you very much for your answer. I can see that in your stack blitz is working flawlessly, but when I try to add that logic to my own code it doesn't work. What are the parameters you are sending to the request update? How are they used? I deleted them and it still works (on your stack blitz) OoO

Comment: in document, it said `To manually start an element update, call requestUpdate with no parameters.` `To implement a custom property setter that supports property options, pass the property name and its previous value as parameters`. In this situation, you can pass no parematers and it still work. I updated answer

Comment: Hello! I know now why it doesn't work. You are using in your package.json lit-element version 2.3.1 My project must use 2.0.0 Do you have a way to achieve it on that version? I can't close the question yet since it still doesn't work :( I'll update to specify it is for lit-element 2.0.0

Comment: not sure what happened with you, i have downgraded lit-element version to 2.0.0 in [stackbliz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/puuhca?file=package.json) and it still work

Comment: After a few (a lot) of hours I found that if I delete a chunk of my own implementation of the firstUpdated() lifecycle method it works. I'll update the question with the code. In 2.3.1 works and in 2.0.0 doesn't, I added that portion of the code to your stack blitz example and it successfully busted it lol. Don't know why, it doesn't make sense since it has nothing to do with the button we are using. The part that says "list.addEventListener()" breaks it

Comment: i updated [stackbliz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/puuhca?file=my-element.js) please check

Comment: do not use `document`, use `this.shadowRoot`, now you can accept my answer :)